# Integral based proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Prove that if $f, g: [a,b] \rightarrow R, f, g \in C([a,b])$ ($f,g$ are continuous and $a, b \ne \infty$) and for every $n \geq 0: \int_{a}^{b}x^{n}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}x^{n}g(x)dx$,

than $f(x) = g(x)$.

I have tried many approaches like taking the Taylor series of $f$ and $g$ and comparing the integrals but nothing worked. I got stuck everywhere since I know that $f$ and $g$ are integrable only one time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As usual, two numbers are equal if and only if their difference is $0$, so consider $h=f-g$. These functions are only continuous, so Taylor series are hopeless. What big theorem *do* you have to use?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Weierstrass approximation theorem.